# Function to strip!, then convert zero-length string to nil

Tags: ruby

What's the most-efficient manner to remove beginning and ending spaces around a string, then convert the string to nil if the resulting value is zero-length?

For example:

```
> a=''
> squash(a)
=> nil

> a='    '
> squash(a)
=> nil

> a='  xyz  '
> squash(a)
=> 'xyz'

> a=nil
> squash(a)
=> nil
```

Thus far:

```
def squash(value)

    return nil if value.nil?

    value.strip!

    (value.blank? ? nil : value)

end
```

Seems like there could be a more-terse way of implementing this.

** edit **

While I am working in Rails, it would be nice if the answer would contain a Ruby-only implementation, too.

I should emphasize that the implementation needs to be able to handle <strike>a string with</strike> a `nil` value.

Comment: What do you mean "string with a nil value"? The string has an embedded nil? That what you think is a string is actually a nil?

Comment: Point taken, @theTinMan.  I want the function to be able to handle `nil` values without raising an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want this for rails (otherwise `blank?` is undefined) you can use `presence` method:

```
def squash(value)
  value && value.strip.presence
end
```

In pure ruby, I would do:

```
def squash(value)
  return unless value
  value = value.strip
  value unless value.empty?
end
```

Comment: I don't believe "presence" is Ruby either.

Comment: @SteffenRoller - It is not, but since he's calling `blank?` I assumed it is for rails. Updated answer.

Comment: I guess so. Just wanted to make it clear. I don't work in Rails only in Ruby as a script language. Therefore I'm often unhappy that many people don't even know the difference. WRT your response: I find it too tricky. IMHO it takes more time to understand what the purpose here is instead of a clear "length == 0". The runtime difference *should* be negligable.

Comment: @SteffenRoller - I think this is a matter of personal preference. In my opinion using ternary operator here can only make code more unreadable. It feels especially wrong when it is to return nil in one of the cases. I am not a huge fan of using `length == 0`, especially when you have ruby buit-in `empty?`

Comment: This works in Rails, thanks.  Do you have a Ruby-only variation?

Answer (score 3):

This will work with plain Ruby:

```
def squash(str)
  str = str.to_s.strip
  str unless str.empty?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
def squash(str)
  (str && str[/\S/]) ? str.strip : nil
end
```

`/\S/` looks for a character that is not whitespace.

```
squash " My dog has fleas. " #=> "My dog has fleas."
squash "                   " #=> nil
squash nil                   #=> nil
```

**Reader challenge**

I tried to also implement `squash!`, that would convert the argument `str` in place.  If `str` is `nil`, just leave it alone.  If `str` contains a least one non-whitespace character, then `str.strip!`. However, I could not figure out a way to convert a string to `nil`. I wanted to do this when the string is empty or contains only whitespace, but the problem is to convert any string, or more generally, any non-nil object, to `nil`, when the object is received as a method argument.  Can it be done? **[Edit:** @Stefan says the type cannot be changed. I'm sure he's right, but I would like to see where that is written and understand why it is not permitted. Anyone? **tidE]**.

Comment: +1 Me like it, but it's not gona work if nil is passed.

Comment: Thanks, @BroiSatse. I didn't notice the last example.  Fixed.

Comment: I like the idea of `squash!`.

Comment: An object's type cannot be changed in Ruby.

Comment: @Stefan, that's the conclusion I came to, but I want proof. Do you know where I can find it?

Answer (score 1):

This handles all your examples.

```
def squash(value)
  value.to_s.strip.empty? ? nil : value.strip
end
```

Comment: Steve, a little less readable, but you could shorten that to `value.strip unless value.to_s.strip.empty?`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yeeessss... but the next coder supporting couldn't be sure if it's my intent or a typo. :)

Comment: So what? You're job 1 is too show other coders how clever you are.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this because it's short:

```
def squash(str)
  str.to_s[/\S(.*\S)?/]
end

squash(nil)         #=> nil
squash("")          #=> nil
squash(" ")         #=> nil
squash("a")         #=> "a"
squash(" a")        #=> "a"
squash("a ")        #=> "a"
squash(" a ")       #=> "a"
squash(" foo ")     #=> "foo"
squash(" foo bar ") #=> "foo bar"
```

Comment: Nice one, @Stefan, but 13 lines is "short"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plain ruby version:

```
def squash(str)
  str && str.strip! && (str unless str.empty?)
end
```

Update - If you want a version without side effects:

```
def squash(str)
  str && (x = str.strip) && (x unless x.empty?)
end
```

Comment: There is a problem here. The correct values are returned, but if `s = " cat "` and `s` is passed as an argument, `s` is changed in place to `"cat"`, probably what the OP wants. If, however, `s = "  "`, `s` is left unchanged.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That doesn't happen on my machine, w/ ruby 2. I get `nil`, as per OP's spec.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if `s = "  "`, `s` is converted to an empty string ( not "left unchanged"), but my point stands. If `s = " cat "`, then `squash(s) => "cat"`, `s => "cat"`. To be consistent with that, we would want `s= "  "`, `squash(s) => nil`, `s => nil`, but we get `s => ""` after `squash(s)`.

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the side effect rather than the return value.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the method name `squash` with argument `value`.

```rb
def squash(value)
  return value unless value.instance_of?(String)
  return if value.strip!&.empty?
  value
end
```

**Features:**

- Works either on `pure Ruby` or `Ruby on Rails`
- Works with other data types than `string` as well, for example, you can pass a `number` if you want

**Testing:**

```rb
squash('ok')
#=> ok
```

```rb
squash('')
#=> nil
```

```rb
squash('    ')
#=> nil
```

```rb
squash('  xyz  ')
#=> 'xyz'
```

```rb
squash('xyz  ')
#=> 'xyz'
```

```rb
squash('    xyz')
#=> 'xyz'
```

```rb
squash(123)
#=> 123
```

```rb
squash(nil)
#=> nil
```

Note:
I use `safe navigation operator`, which was released in [Ruby 2.3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/). So make sure before using it.

Answer (score -1):

```
irb(main):001:0> s = " string "
=> " string "
irb(main):002:0> s.strip!
=> "string"
irb(main):003:0> s.blank?
NoMethodError: undefined method `blank?' for "string":String
        from (irb):3
        from C:/RUBY/BIN/irb:12:in `'
irb(main):004:0>
```

I think `blank` is not Ruby but Rails? Anyway, what's wrong with

```
(value.length == 0 ? nil : value)
```

or even better

```
value.empty? ? nil : value
```

At least everybody would understand what the intention is here.

Comment: I would like to have `strip!` and `empty?` check combined in a way that calling them doesn't raise an `NoMethodError` exception, which will occur is the string is `nil`.

Comment: then you could just do... `value.to_s.strip.empty? ? nil : value.strip`